# Как использовать расстояние Левенштейна для двух массивов?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть два массива. В одном поступившая строка, которая разбивается на массив, второй массив это список правильных слов. Как с помощью `levenshtein()` в первом массиве проверить все значения, чтобы соответствовали словам во втором массиве? На php.net нашел пример только когда одно поступившее слово сравнивается с массивом. 
Пытался доработать, но `foreach` внутри другого `foreach` не хочет работать

```php
//Поступивший массив значений
$inputs = array('ккая', 'хорошая', 'погодка', 'сегодня');

// массив сверяемых слов
$words  = array('какая','погода','хорошая','сегодня');

// кратчайшее расстояние пока еще не найдено
$shortest = -1;


foreach ($inputs as $input){

// проходим по словам для нахождения самого близкого варианта
foreach ($words as $word) {

    // вычисляем расстояние между входным словом и текущим
    $lev = levenshtein($input, $word);

    // проверяем полное совпадение
    if ($lev == 0) {

        // это ближайшее слово (точное совпадение)
        $closest = $word;
        $shortest = 0;

        // выходим из цикла - мы нашли точное совпадение
        break;
    }

    // если это расстояние меньше следующего наименьшего расстояния
    // ИЛИ если следующее самое короткое слово еще не было найдено
    if ($lev <= $shortest || $shortest < 0) {
        // set the closest match, and shortest distance
        $closest  = $word;
        $shortest = $lev;
    }
}

echo "Вы ввели: $input<br>";
if ($shortest == 0) {
    echo "Найдено точное совпадение: $closest<br>";
} 
if ($shortest < 3 && $shortest > 0){
    echo "Вы не имели в виду: $closest?<br>";
}
if ($shortest > 2){
    echo "Слов в массиве не найдено<br>";
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Перенесите `$shortest = -1;` внутрь первого `foreach`, чтобы сбрасывать его для каждого слова. Будет ли корректным полученный результат для введённой фразы "Какая какая погода?" и заданной эталонной фразой? Или имеет смысл удалять уже встреченные фразы из дальнейшего поиска?

Comment: @br3t, спасибо, внесение `shortest` помогло. Нет, удалять не стоит. Тут скорее нужно было восстановить слова, чтобы потом проще было обрабатывать массив.